# Remote login to a computer running Win7 from WinXP works only once

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

I have a problem logging in remote to all our test machines/servers running Win7 or WinServer2008 from my computer running WinXP. I am able to login only once and once I close the session and try to reconnect, I get the error message:

> Please enter new credentials for computerName. The credentials that
>   were used to connect to the remote computer did not work.

I tried with the full computer name (computer.domain.net), short name (computer) and IP address but I'm able to login only once per each option.

Are there any settings which they cause this? Or how else this problems could be solved?

Comment: "Please enter new credentials for computerName. The credentials that were used to connect to the remote computer did not work."

Comment: try Teamviewer, Log me in or some other program if everything you tried doesn't work :)

Comment: Your question confuses me slightly in that you can only login once per option, but what is resetting this? A new day, a reboot, other?

Comment: @DaveRook I usually hibernate my laptop so once I start it next day, I'm not able to login to the remote servers... For some of them, reboot helps though; for others, it helps only for one of the options (i.e. I can login using the IP address but cannot using the computername).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

Go to your Local Policy editor :

Start ---> Run and type : gpedit.msc

then Navigate to **Computer Configuration** > **Administrative Templates** > **System** > **Credentials Delegation**

[image]
Then Open Policy **Allow Delegating Saved Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication**

[image]

Set Policy status to **Enabled**

Click on **Show** next to Add servers to the list

Add all servers you are connecting to in format TERMSRV/ where  - IP address or DNS name

You are allowed to use wildcards. e.g. TERMSRV/* would allow access to all servers

Close all dialog boxes saving changes

Open command prompt and run **gpupdate /force**

Comment: I didn't get it, should I do that on my computer? Or on the remotes? I tried to run `gpedit.msc` on my PC with WinXP but I don't have `System > Credentials Delegation` under `Administrative Templates`...